# How to fix search prompt for an inventory program?

Tags: python

I have an inventory program that has 5 different options. 1-3 work and five will shortly. Option 4 "Search Inventory" is the problem. After adding items into the program through option 1, type 98, then 4. I just this error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'update' referenced before assignment.

Here is the full code:

```
import os


name = []

qty = []

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.qty = qty

def menuDisplay():
    print ('=============================')
    print ('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print ('=============================')
    print ('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print ('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print ('(3) Update Inventory')
    print ('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print ('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print ('(99) Quit')
    CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
    menuSelection(CHOICE)

def menuSelection(CHOICE):

    if CHOICE == 1:
        print('Adding Inventory')
        print('================')
        new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        name.append(new_name)
        new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
        qty.append(new_qty)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print('Removing Inventory')
        print('==================')
        removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
        indexdel = name.index(removing)
        name.pop(indexdel)
        qty.pop(indexdel)
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print('Updating Inventory')
        print('==================')
        item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
        update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
    if update >= 0:
        qty[name.index(item)] += update
        print("Update made")
    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif update <= -1:
        qty[name.index(item)] -= update
        print("Update Made")
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print('Searching Inventory')
        print('===================')
        search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        if search == name:
            print ('Item:     ', name.index(search))
            print ('Quantity: ', qty.index)
            print ('----------')
        if search != name:
            print("Item not in inventory")
    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
            menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
    elif CHOICE == 5:
        print('Current Inventory')
        print('=================')
        input('Enter the name of the item: ')
        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
    if CHOICE == 98:
        menuDisplay()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()
        printInventory()
    elif CHOICE == 99:
        exit()

menuDisplay()
```

Comment: you have way too many if's statements at the same level. It seems some are logically following other choices, but too many are tested at the main menu level.

When you hit `4` , the fourt'h `if` checks the condition `update >= 0`, but this `update` variable has never been set. Try to indent some checks under where they belong, so they don't get check when they shouldn't. (and move some code to functions to avoid cluttering your main program)

Comment: Not directly answering the question, but you should replace the repeated if 98 / elif 99 blocks by putting your menu and user input in a while loop. See [Return back to main menu in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47258113/2745495). Once the flow is cleaner, it will be more obvious why `update` is not yet available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't required that you enter items with choice #1 and then type `98` before selecting choice #4.  The problem occurs if all you do is immediately select choice #4.

The reason for this is that entering `4` will allow the code to get to this line:

```
if update >= 0:
```

This line throws an exception because no value has ever been assigned to `update`.  Looking at your code, the only place that you assign a value to `update` is when your code is processing a user's entry of `3`, here:

```
elif CHOICE == 3:
    print('Updating Inventory')
    print('==================')
    item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
    update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
```

Since that choice hasn't ever been chosen, `update` has never been set, and so you get the exception you're seeing.

I don't know your logic well enough to be sure how you should fix this.  Maybe assign a value of `0` to `update` at the beginning of the `menuSelection` function.