# How can you go back to a line of code while running?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple money/xp level system for a text pokemon type game I am making. That is kind of out of the point but the commands are taken from a single input

edit: How do I make it go "ONCE" and then go back?

```
  print("type your first command. . .\n")
  fc = input("")
  if (fc == "search"):
    while (fc == "search"):
      if (random.randint(1, 100) < 50):
        print("YOU FOUND A WILD " + pokemon)
  elif (fc == "stats"):

  elif (fc == "pokemon"):
    
  elif (fc == "help"):
    print("Here are the commands:")
    print("Type 'help' to go back to this window")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Type 'search' to look for pokemon")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Type 'stats' to see you wins/losses and money")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Type 'pokemon' to see what pokemon there are in this game")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("and thats it for commands, have fun!\n\n")






else:
  print("That is not a valid option")'
```

How would I go back to the fc input command or the simplest way to get around this?

Comment: Just use a `while` loop

Comment: You wrap the whole thing in a loop, where the top of the loop is the `fc` input statement.

Comment: `while (fc == "search"):` is an infinite loop. `fc` doesn't change inside the loop.

Comment: I know but sometimes it wont stop and will keep going

Comment: I dont want a loop, I want it to run once and then go back

Comment: _"I dont want a loop, I want it to run once and then go back"_ That's exactly what a loop does. A loop runs once and then goes back.

Comment: **I know but sometimes it wont stop and will keep going -** just use `break` wherever u wanna exit the loop.

Comment: Ok, I am new to this and I hear loop and think infinite, thank you

Comment: @Xahann An infinite loop is usually a bug.  You just need to use the appropriate exit test for the loop to prevent it from being infinite.

Comment: See: [How to return to the main menu in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47258113/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a while loop. I also removed the infinite loop.

```
while True:
  fc = input("type your first command. . .\n\n")
  if fc == "search":
    if (random.randint(1, 100) < 50):
      print("YOU FOUND A WILD " + pokemon)
  elif fc == "stats":
    pass
  elif fc == "pokemon":
    pass
  elif fc == "help":
    print("Here are the commands:")
    print("Type 'help' to go back to this window")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Type 'search' to look for pokemon")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Type 'stats' to see you wins/losses and money")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Type 'pokemon' to see what pokemon there are in this game")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("and thats it for commands, have fun!\n\n")
  elif fc == "exit":
    break
  else:
    print("That is not a valid option")
```